# How to translate a solution into divide-and-conquer (finding a sub array with the largest, smallest value)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to get better at divide an conquer algorithms and am using this one below as an example. Given an array `_in` and some length `l` it finds the start point of a sub array `_in[_min_start,_min_start+l]` such that the lowest value in that sub array is the highest it could possible be. I have come up with a none divide and conquer solution and am wondering how I could go about translating this into one which divides the array up into smaller parts (divide-and-conquer).

```py
def main(_in, l):
    _min_start = 0
    min_trough = None

    for i in range(len(_in)+1-l):
        if min_trough is None:
            min_trough = min(_in[i:i+l])
        
        if min(_in[i:i+l]) > min_trough:
            _min_start = i
            min_trough = min(_in[i:i+l])
    
    return _min_start, _in[_min_start:_min_start+l]
```

e.g. For the array `[5, 1, -1, 2, 5, -4, 3, 9, 8, -2, 0, 6]` and a sub array of lenght `3` it would return start position 6 (resulting in the array `[3,9,8]`).

Comment: What makes you think that divide-and-conquer is useful for this problem?

Comment: @maraca Or just do it in O(n) and then you have a clear winner :-P

Comment: @user3386109 Well there is one :-) (I'd post it if the question didn't specifically ask for d&c).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Fair enough. As a minimum, OP needs to respond to your first comment, since OP seems to be asking how to pound on a nail with a screwdriver :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Ahh, pound on the array with a stack, I guess.

Comment: @user3386109 Not sure about stack, I used a deque. But I'm guessing we mean the same algorithm.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode its not that I think it is useful its that the problem requires me to explore the the divide-and-conquer route

Comment: @user3386109 Actually by now I have *three* O(n) solutions :-). The monoqueue one is the one I suspect you sort of had in mind, is that right? Or is yours yet another way?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Yes the monoqueue solution is the one I had in mind. Seems like you've covered every aspect of the problem, well done :)

Comment: @user3386109 Well, every aspect until yet another person comes around with something to add :-) (both the linearity of the divide-and-conquer solution and the k-blocks solution stemmed from comments of others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Three O(n) solutions and a benchmark

Note I'm renaming _in and l to clearer-looking names A and k.

#### Solution 1: Divide and conquer

Split the array in half. Solve left half and right half recursively. The subarrays not yet considered cross the middle, i.e., they're a suffix of the left part plus a prefix of the right part. Compute k-1 suffix-minima of the left half and k-1 prefix-minima of the right half. That allows you to compute the minimum for each middle-crossing subarray of length k in O(1) time each. The best subarray for the whole array is the best of left-best, right-best and crossing-best.

Runtime is O(n), I believe. As Ellis pointed out, in the recursion the subarray can become smaller than k. Such cases take O(1) time to return the equivalent of *"there aren't any k-length subarrays in here"*. So the time is:

```
T(n) = { 2 * T(n/2) + O(k)    if n >= k
       { O(1)                 otherwise
```

For any 0 <= k <= n we have k=n<sup>c</sup> with 0 <= c <= 1. Then the number of calls is Θ(n<sup>1-c</sup>) and each call's own work takes Θ(n<sup>c</sup>) time, for a total of Θ(n) time.

Posted a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144780/143319) about the complexity to be sure.

Python implementation:

```
def solve_divide_and_conquer(A, k):
    def solve(start, stop):
        if stop - start < k:
            return -inf,
        mid = (start + stop) // 2
        left = solve(start, mid)
        right = solve(mid, stop)
        i0 = mid - k + 1
        prefixes = accumulate(A[mid:mid+k-1], min)
        if i0 < 0:
            prefixes = [*prefixes][-i0:]
            i0 = 0
        suffixes = list(accumulate(A[i0:mid][::-1], min))[::-1]
        crossing = max(zip(map(min, suffixes, prefixes), count(i0)))
        return max(left, right, crossing)
    return solve(0, len(A))[1]
```

#### Solution 2: k-Blocks

As commented by @benrg, the above dividing-and-conquering is needlessly complicated. We can simply work on blocks of length k. Compute the suffix minima of the first block and the prefix minima of the second block. That allows finding the minimum of each k-length subarray within these two blocks in O(1) time. Do the same with the second and third block, the third and fourth block, etc. Time is O(n) as well.

Python implementation:

```
def solve_blocks(A, k):
    return max(max(zip(map(min, prefixes, suffixes), count(mid-k)))
               for mid in range(k, len(A)+1, k)
               for prefixes in [accumulate(A[mid:mid+k], min, initial=inf)]
               for suffixes in [list(accumulate(A[mid-k:mid][::-1], min, initial=inf))[::-1]]
           )[1]
```

#### Solution 3: Monoqueue

Not divide & conquer, but first one I came up with (and knew was O(n)).

Sliding window, represent the window with a deque of (sorted) indexes of strictly increasing array values in the window. When sliding the window to include a new value `A[i]`:

1. Remove the first index from the deque if the sliding makes it fall out of the window.
2. Remove indexes whose array values are larger than `A[i]`. (They can never be the minimum of the window anymore.)
3. Include the new index `i`.
4. The first index still in the deque is the index of the current window's minimum value. Use that to update overall result.

Python implementation:

```
from collections import deque

A = [5, 1, -1, 2, 5, -4, 3, 9, 8, -2, 0, 6]
k = 3

I = deque()
for i in range(len(A)):
    if I and I[0] == i - k:
        I.popleft()
    while I and A[I[-1]] >= A[i]:
        I.pop()
    I.append(i)
    curr_min = A[I[0]]
    if i == k-1 or i > k-1 and curr_min > max_min:
        result = i - k + 1
        max_min = curr_min

print(result)
```

#### Benchmark

With 4000 numbers from the range 0 to 9999, and k=2000:

```
 80.4 ms   81.4 ms   81.8 ms  solve_brute_force
 80.2 ms   80.5 ms   80.7 ms  solve_original
  2.4 ms    2.4 ms    2.4 ms  solve_monoqueue
  2.4 ms    2.4 ms    2.4 ms  solve_divide_and_conquer
  1.3 ms    1.4 ms    1.4 ms  solve_blocks
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZLj6Q2EL7zKyytVgvTdC@9k0gRWkZq5TSXXHJECDFQPW0BNrHNZiZ/flJ@YExPj7JBarVxVX311cNlpld14ez@t0m8vZ0FH4miI1BF6DhxoYiACRoVGYloWId/TtJeOG1BWhFVIBTng1ykTdvO4zw0CqzC2KjLIqPs/IFVy2fmnLV8GKBVlDMv7eCvGaKogzORfPgB9cgZx60Z4lNK@iSPCD6PpLCacWLez1wQij41/WeIB2DxKXG6@qFnNMHIyGOZVaQoUHlP@lVuMA8TnwY4K4epn78vdABneiofy/2xqshDgWta3bAOLB8PzTQB62K67rWzEPWILAsDllVVSJBqXv3@SEwsD2ap/XqrB0zwi15tPQuQ86CIi4nsyHEjdjYoX4Aia6VmwZxxmO@O/qAd1Oi5bjnDFIsw8V4vlqoRKiVS8WmbaL2DTIycfL/OsvO7x/5IvWCkHfKzkBiAwSRfv5JvXkPXBVU2rtFqza2gz5dVA0WO2sosQ6l2dJ2kScCZvoBE8drQ8alE3Rx/O6xDpZ2xZFOtDGPLtrEFSOXd8lKVe5rl1UbRcMn8lpzPi91ApYo3NNAYWVRlnnseiX1Z@0pwKSl71gE2L/E/dIrHBn@UpR479eyS1B7BmGZJEiTQFkYD6GSnNqOpB0/CtrFZzlLiTlqJbIIeehp428uwbwL0dxQXYitZTxEj3/chS/fo865r6U98v1DZHbXTW/q@OmhU3q60zW@KGlTRZiiwSZPqFpavmMZ6XzND@7psW1hXww26SePyEqZTzApq9NvCBzkNx97uiClLr1n38FoMzfjUNfZk5poSUrVnLrebmAHMdeCZYxNQ1gxxrfkPzrEeIrU1XNpY7yjB5@cLbv3BGY7wD@YyImmKw3ZoBPZUGoDt0drga@YIU9Kc7oZqLfYVYKijh6eH2EJvoqH/z2tYhwCHfCIp0brrXr4u0TqKML@zvfhwWBiYd7VOg@2lEOGevxnDzffjO5Tag5lGSECXpl5Lc@/qcdIXhb31XVcdM3zwRPbFL3phtHrU@oZvtsqfyO8XaHs8s0Lgdc5ASrMPLxO@Lg3hz46LXPv2WQiagXXwYge5EcWnQ8un1zjZnOtGSvysIDiEC2ehr0q72pmr87sbCNGmmBcQ4GqJo9Wo59ZM937YQI78zW70gXnMq3uA4uyySismDBLyG3oBr8Ihpz76Q12zZoS6tjjWIlnS/ucE0P1sYnUW9ZeHS6ffV9JkWyjoYvslGNtBka810CY6/ylh8/gEojjqAXZfRdtQ7uIvn389HPH0SfKFfCaxInfkCPeJ4ac/CtFb8l/Rvb39Cw)):

```
from timeit import repeat
from random import choices
from itertools import accumulate
from math import inf
from itertools import count
from collections import deque

def solve_monoqueue(A, k):
    I = deque()
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if I and I[0] == i - k:
            I.popleft()
        while I and A[I[-1]] >= A[i]:
            I.pop()
        I.append(i)
        curr_min = A[I[0]]
        if i == k-1 or i > k-1 and curr_min > max_min:
            result = i - k + 1
            max_min = curr_min
    return result

def solve_divide_and_conquer(A, k):
    def solve(start, stop):
        if stop - start < k:
            return -inf,
        mid = (start + stop) // 2
        left = solve(start, mid)
        right = solve(mid, stop)
        i0 = mid - k + 1
        prefixes = accumulate(A[mid:mid+k-1], min)
        if i0 < 0:
            prefixes = [*prefixes][-i0:]
            i0 = 0
        suffixes = list(accumulate(A[i0:mid][::-1], min))[::-1]
        crossing = max(zip(map(min, suffixes, prefixes), count(i0)))
        return max(left, right, crossing)
    return solve(0, len(A))[1]

def solve_blocks(A, k):
    return max(max(zip(map(min, prefixes, suffixes), count(mid-k)))
               for mid in range(k, len(A)+1, k)
               for prefixes in [accumulate(A[mid:mid+k], min, initial=inf)]
               for suffixes in [list(accumulate(A[mid-k:mid][::-1], min, initial=inf))[::-1]]
           )[1]
        
def solve_brute_force(A, k):
    return max(range(len(A)+1-k),
               key=lambda start: min(A[start : start+k]))

def solve_original(_in, l):
    _min_start = 0
    min_trough = None

    for i in range(len(_in)+1-l):
        if min_trough is None:
            min_trough = min(_in[i:i+l])
        
        if min(_in[i:i+l]) > min_trough:
            _min_start = i
            min_trough = min(_in[i:i+l])
    
    return _min_start  # , _in[_min_start:_min_start+l]

solutions = [
    solve_brute_force,
    solve_original,
    solve_monoqueue,
    solve_divide_and_conquer,
    solve_blocks,
]

for _ in range(3):
    A = choices(range(10000), k=4000)
    k = 2000

    # Check correctness
    expect = None
    for solution in solutions:
        index = solution(A.copy(), k)
        assert 0 <= index and index + k-1 < len(A)
        min_there = min(A[index : index+k])
        if expect is None:
            expect = min_there
            print(expect)
        else:
            print(min_there == expect, solution.__name__)
    print()

    # Speed
    for solution in solutions:
        copy = A.copy()
        ts = sorted(repeat(lambda: solution(copy, k), number=1))[:3]
        print(*('%5.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in ts), solution.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: So when I split the array in half, what do I do if the array size < k?

Comment: @EllisThompson Then it doesn't have a subarray long enough, so just immediately return something like `None` or the (min,index) pair `(-∞, None)` (whatever is most convenient for the caller, which might be the recursive function itself). I guess I could use that to make my runtime analysis tighter, but it looks ugly enough already :-)

Comment: @EllisThompson Actually now I convinced myself that because of this, the divide and conquer solution is O(n) as well.

Comment: The divide-and-conquer algorithm is O(n), but I think it has no advantage over just iterating over blocks of length k from left to right. The iterative version avoids the overhead of recursive calls and does less redundant work when n/k isn't a power of 2. You can still use the trick with suffix and prefix minima.

Comment: @benrg Hmm, I think you're right. And I've implemented the divide&conquer solution, but it still has a little bug because of edge-case-nastyness. Your simpler blocks way might also eliminate that edge case. I'll implement that as well.

Comment: @benrg Done, see the added solutions and benchmark results. The edge-case-nastyness that I mentioned for the divide-and-conquer solution is the `i0 < 0` case. That doesn't even happen in the k-blocks solution. (I'm btw aware I'm double-computing the minimum for each subarray that's exactly an inner k-block, but it doesn't hurt much and I'm afraid optimizing that away would slightly complicate the code.)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Thanks for your help, and I appreciate the through evaluation of method. Sadly, despite D&C being somewhat needless in this case, the solution was required to be D&C :/

Comment: @EllisThompson Did your instructor share their solution as well? I'd be interested in knowing whether it's the same as mine or yet another way, and what they're saying about their complexity.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Not yet, it was submitted this morning. I'll update when I have the example solution :)